# NodeJS: Rise and fall of Heap memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have a NodeJs server handling about 3-4 requests per second. The heap memory graph looks like this:

[image: Heap usage for memory]

Since the memory usage drops back down, it seems like the GC is happening properly. But because total heap usage should be more or less constant, could there be a memory leak happening here?

Comment: Are those hours on the horizontal scale?

Comment: @Bergi yes they are

Comment: It does look like your memory allocation is hitting a threshold and that GC is aggressively clearing up space once it does so.

Comment: @NickWyman is this a problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: It essentially means that you have objects that aren't being caught by minor cycles of garbage collection. But it is being caught in the major cycle of garbage collection. So you don't have a runaway memory leak, but it can definitely be optimized. You can find more details in this [article](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection)